# Are "Iterable", "Iterator" examples of types in python?

Tags: python

This is a question about how python's (dynamic) type system works. I have read articles online saying that to define a class to be "an iterable", we need to define a `__iter__` function for it. We don't in fact have to explicitly state that that class "is an iterable". I would have guessed based on experience with other languages that I'd have to write something like

```py
class Foo extends Iterable:
   def __iter__(self):
      return self
```

When I test the type of `Foo` and one of its instances I get:

```py
print(type(Foo))
print(type(Foo()))
print(isinstance(Foo(), collections.abc.Iterable))
```

Output:

```
<class 'type'>
<class '__main__.Foo'>
True
```

My question is: What is the status of a concept like "Iterable" in python's (dynamic) type system? Should I think of it as having anything to do with types at all?

Comment: I think the word for this, in Python, is “[conforms to] protocol” — https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0544/  ; https://jarombek.com/blog/dec-15-2018-python-protocols-abcs — the linked PEP title is “Protocols: *structural* subtyping”. In a statically typed language like Java this is “nominative (*by bass type name*) subtyping”.

Comment: Python is a duck-typed language, that means an object is defined by its abilities and not by declarations. "When I see a bird that walks like a duck and swims like a duck and quacks like a duck, I call that bird a duck." --James Whitcomb Rileys

Answer (score 5):

A `type` is what python calls any object that's been defined via a `class` statement. Using Java as a reference point, `type` is akin to [`java.lang.Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) - the class that represents classes.

"Iterable" is more akin to an *interface* than a *class* - whereas a class/type defines both an internal state and certain methods, an interface only defines those methods. Python doesn't formalize this like other languages, but the principle is used in most of python's "hidden" methods (the ones that have two underscores on both sides). If a particular hidden method is defined for a class (for example, `__iter__()`), then that class is considered to be iterable*.

In your example, you use `isinstance()` to prove your point. [The python documentation actually has a page on `collections.abc`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html), which goes into detail about their behavior:

> This module provides abstract base classes that can be used to test whether a class **provides a particular interface**; for example, whether it is hashable or whether it is a mapping.

(bold added for emphasis).

And it even mentions Iterators specifically:

> **`class collections.abc.Iterable`**
>
> > ABC for classes that provide the `__iter__()` method.
> >
> > Checking `isinstance(obj, Iterable)` detects classes that are registered as Iterable or that have an `__iter__()` method, but it does not detect classes that iterate with the `__getitem__()` method. The only reliable way to determine whether an object is iterable is to call `iter(obj)`.

Python allows for ABC classes essentially hijack the builtin `isinstance()` call [via defining the `__instancecheck__()` metaclass method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks), which is why `isinstance(Foo(), Iterable)` is able to return True despite `Foo` not inheriting from `Iterable`.

---

*while the inputs and outputs for these functions aren't as strictly defined as in static-typed languages like Java, the built-in methods that call them have *very specific expectations* that, in effect, result in the same thing. For example, I once ran into a problem trying to override `__len__()` on an object to return a float instead of an int, because the built-in `len()` threw an error when I tried to use it on that object.